# possessive and adjective form of "the 1920s"

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

What's the possessive or adjective form of **the 1920s**? Is it **the 1920s'** (with an apostrophe following the **s**)?
Most books only talk about the plural form, which I think is a settled issue, but the adjective or possessive form of the decade has not been discussed.

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to be "discussed." Making 1920s possessive is just like making anything possessive (e.g., *The 1920s' roar was quite loud and often accompanied by much flapping.*).

Comment: Some people say the plural 1920s itself can function as an adjective without an apostrophe.

Comment: Sure, it can. That's no different, either. You'd say, "The Empire State Building's architecture is 1920s art deco," just like you'd say, "The White House's architecture is 18th-century neoclassical." Nobody would say "The White House's architecture is 18th century's neoclassical," so naturally, "1920s" in its sentence isn't possessive, either.

Comment: There must be some common uneasiness with bare “1920s” as an attributive, else I wouldn't so often see phrases of the redundant form “1920s-era architecture”.